# Upload notes fanpage with grap api facebook

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Hi I am using this code to post a note on my fan page, it works, the problem is that the diary page does not show the image, but only the text, why?

```
<?php
$access_token='MY ACCES TOKEN FAN PAGE';
$attachment = array(
'access_token' => $access_token,
'message' => 'MESSAGE <img src="IMAGE_ADDRESS" alt="TEST IMAGE" /> ',
'subject' => 'test test test'
);

// set the target url
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://graph.facebook.com/id_fanpage/notes?');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false); //to suppress the curl output

$result= curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you uploading the image?

It seems that the `notes`'s `message` field accepts HTML tags and hence having something like the below should work:

```
<img src='http://domain.com/myImage.jpg' />
```

Comment: image as you can see from the code I'm inserting into the message field with html tags <img>, the problem is that the diary page does not show any preview image but if I click on the note is shown the image, how can I fix this?

Comment: So the image does appear when you are on the note full view? where's the image in your message body? maybe if it's at the bottom the preview won't show it (I haven't test the notes api before)

Comment: That's right, the image is displayed when you open the note in full as you can see here '-> http://www.facebook.com/pages/Test-page/302269416561381, the img tag with the image is placed in the field "message"